# R convert output list from runner to a data frame

Tags: r

Could you please help me to convert a list coming from the runner function into a data frame.

Here is my simplified example:

```
library(runner)
 
 # Random Data
 rdata <- data.frame(ID=seq(100),A=runif(100),B=runif(100))

head(rdata)
  ID         A          B
1  1 0.4566914 0.62081081
2  2 0.3931568 0.38796394
3  3 0.4155734 0.91134851
4  4 0.6471508 0.96903488
5  5 0.4087917 0.02486545
6  6 0.1460227 0.62266711

 # Some function with data frame as an output
 foo <- function(RDATA){
   A_MinMax <- c(which.max(RDATA$A),which.min(RDATA$A))
   B_MinMax <- c(which.max(RDATA$B),which.min(RDATA$B))
   data.frame(A_MinMax,B_MinMax)
 }
 
 # Moving window with list as an output
 Output <- runner::runner(
   x = rdata, 
   k = 10,
   idx ="ID",
   at = seq(10,100,10),
   lag = 0,
   f = function(x){foo(RDATA=x)}
 )

 Output
 
[,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]      [,8]     
A_MinMax integer,2 integer,2 integer,2 integer,2 integer,2 integer,2 integer,2 integer,2
B_MinMax integer,2 integer,2 integer,2 integer,2 integer,2 integer,2 integer,2 integer,2
         [,9]      [,10]    
A_MinMax integer,2 integer,2
B_MinMax integer,2 integer,2

 # List structure
 str(Output)

List of 20
 $ : int [1:2] 8 10
 $ : int [1:2] 4 5
 $ : int [1:2] 10 9
 $ : int [1:2] 5 10
 $ : int [1:2] 4 10
 $ : int [1:2] 9 3
 $ : int [1:2] 5 9
 $ : int [1:2] 10 4
 $ : int [1:2] 9 2
 $ : int [1:2] 6 8
 $ : int [1:2] 3 7
 $ : int [1:2] 6 3
 $ : int [1:2] 10 6
 $ : int [1:2] 3 7
 $ : int [1:2] 8 1
 $ : int [1:2] 5 1
 $ : int [1:2] 7 3
 $ : int [1:2] 8 5
 $ : int [1:2] 10 5
 $ : int [1:2] 1 6
 - attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 2 10
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "A_MinMax" "B_MinMax"
  ..$ : NULL
 
 # Loop for converting the list in a data frame
  for (i in 1:2){
   res <-data.frame()
   res <- rbind.data.frame(res,as.data.frame(Output[,i]))
   res
 }
 
 # The loop is storing in "res" only the last "i"=2
 res
 
  A_MinMax B_MinMax
1       10        5
2        9       10

 # Desired output
 rbind.data.frame(as.data.frame(Output[,1]),as.data.frame(Output[,2]))

  A_MinMax B_MinMax
1        8        4
2       10        5
3       10        5
4        9       10
```

I cannot store via loop all lists from the main list in a single data frame as in the example above. I am also wondering, why the loop is only saving the last "i".

Best regards,

John

Answer (score 1):

This does the trick, but I'm wondering if there is not a more condensed way with base R functions.

```
library(tidyr)
separate_rows(data.frame(t(Output))) %>% 
  unnest(cols = c(A_MinMax, B_MinMax))

# A tibble: 20 x 2
   A_MinMax B_MinMax
      <int>    <int>
 1        2        6
 2        8       10
 3        7        2
 4        8        7
 5        3        8
 6        5        9
 7        9        4
 8        5        8
 9        4        8
10        3        2
11        4        3
12        5        8
13        2        1
14        6        9
15        6        7
16       10        6
17        5        1
18        9        9
19        4        2
20        2        6
```

**data I used:**

```
set.seed(42)
rdata <- data.frame(ID=seq(100),A=runif(100),B=runif(100))
```